# setFocusable on button click

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have a small timer app and EditText widgets named `etH`, `etM` and `etS` which allow input and show the time ticking. When the start button is clicked and the timer is started, I forbid the interaction by doing the following:

```
btnS.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
    if (calculateMS() != 0) {
        OnTimerStartButtonClicked();
        initiateTimer();
        DisableEditTexts();
                    ...
```

The method:

```
public void DisableEditTexts() {
    etH.setFocusable(false);
    etM.setFocusable(false);
    etS.setFocusable(false);
}
```

By pressing the reset button I want to re-enable the interaction by calling the method the does the reverse thing (sets focusable to true):

```
btnR.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        OnTimerResetButtonClicked();
        clearValues();
        EnableEditTexts();
        ...
```

The problem: the edittexts do NOT become focusable by clicking the reset button. All I'm doing in last method is

```
etH.setFocusable(true);
etM.setFocusable(true);
etS.setFocusable(true);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try calling [`EditText#setFocusableInTouchMode()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setFocusableInTouchMode%28boolean%29) instead:

```
etH.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
// etc.
```

---

When you call `setFocusable(false)`, behind the scenes, `setFocusableInTouchMode(false)` is called for you. However when you call `setFocusable(true)`, nothing else happens behind the scenes, leaving `setFocusableInTouchMode()` as `false`.

When you call `setFocusableInTouchMode(true)`, a similar thing happens, `setFocusable(true)` is called for you. And the same as before `setFocusableInTouchMode(false)`, does not call `setFocuable(false)`.

Take a peak at the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.1_r1/android/view/View.java#View.setFocusable%28boolean%29) to see this quirk.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried debugging to make sure EnableEditTexts() is actually getting called when you press the reset button?

Answer (score 0):

Try _myEditText.clearFocus() to lose focus and _myEditText.requestFocus() to regain it